# future url doesn't load in webview

Tags: flutter

I'm using this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) for a webview in my app. The url needed is a future. The`url` is got by a `FutureBuilder`. (No problem with the future) However the page doesn't load in the web view. Here is a minimal example. Hard coding `https://www.google.com/` works(The google page is loaded). However when I get the the url via a FB it doesn't work... Any suggestions....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Future<String> url;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Web'),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: url,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final url = snapshot.data;
                return WebView(
                  initialUrl: url,  // If I hardcode https://www.google.com/ it will work.
                );
              })),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    url = _getFutureUrl();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> _getFutureUrl() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((onValue) => 'https://www.google.com/');
  }
}
```

Comment: add `if (url == null) return CupertinoActivityIndicator();`